# Нужно найти разницу между двумя датами.JS

Tags: javascript

```
function rev(hours, minutes, seconds) {
            console.log(hours * 3.600 + minutes * 60 + seconds)
        }
//это функция чтобы перевести часы и минуты в секунды


        function sec(a) {
            let h = Math.round(a / 3600) % 60
            let m = Math.round(a / 60 % 60)
            let sec1 = a % 60
            console.log(h  + ':', + m, ':',+ sec1)
        }
//эта функция наоборот 
        function dif(h1, m1, s1, h2, m2, s2){
            console.log(h1  + ':', + m1, ':',+ s1)
            console.log(h2  + ':', + m2, ':',+ s2)
            let res = h1, m1, s1
            let res2 = h2, m2, s2
            return rev(res), rev(res2)}
            console.log(dif(1, 22, 33, 3, 22, 55))
//здесь нужно сравнить две даты,которых вводит пользователь,но нужно вызвать сначала первую функцию и перевести все в секунды, сравнить разницу, и только потом опять вернуть в первоначальный вариант
```

Comment: На всякий случай напомню, что `3.600` и `3600` это не одно и то же

Comment: О,спасибо,не заметила

Comment: @zin если хотите разделять тысячи в числе 3600, в JS можно писать вот так: `3_600`